# Cannot get the yOffset of an Element

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, scroll, offset

I'm reading an array of sporting fixtures from firebase and displaying them as ion-cards on screen.

Each ion-card is assigned an element id and I want to get the yOffset for a particular ion-card and on loading of the screen scroll directly to that ion-card.

The yOffset always seems to return 0 even though that particular element is not on the screen ... you have to scroll down to it.

```
    ngOnInit(){
        this.matchService.getMatches().get().then(matchSnapshot => {
            this.matches= [];
            matchSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                this.matches.push ({  
                id: snap.id,
                    date: snap.data().date,
                    team: snap.data().team,
                     home: snap.data().home,
                    away: snap.data().away,
                     homeScore: snap.data().homeScore,
                    awayScore: snap.data().awayScore,
                });
                 return false;
                 });                

            var elementID = 
this.getElementIdOfFixtureClosestToToday(this.matches);
            setTimeout(()=>{this.scrollToYOffsetOfElement(elementID);},3000);          
        });   
    }
```

this.getElementIdOfFixtureClosestToToday succesfully returns the elementd ID I want

```
 private scrollToYOffsetOfElement(element: string){

        let yOffset = document.getElementById(element).offsetTop;
        console.log("yOffset = " + yOffset);
        this.content.scrollToPoint(0,yOffset,300);
        }
```

My HTML code

```
<ion-content #content>

     <ion-card *ngFor="let match of matches; let i = index"  tappable 
routerLink="/../match-details-standard/{{match.id}}" >

        <ion-card-content id='{{i}}'>    
            <ion-grid >
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                    <ion-col class="team" col-3>{{match?.team}}</ion-col>
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                </ion-row>

                <!-- matchNotPlayed: If the match has been played then I 
don't want to show the day which it was played -->
                <ion-row *ngIf="match?.homeScore != ''; else matchNotPlayed">
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col col-3>{{match?.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'d MMM yy' }}</ion-col>
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                    <ion-col></ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ng-template #matchNotPlayed>
                    <ion-row> {{match?.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'EE d MMM yy' }}</ion-row>
                </ng-template> 
                <!-- matchNotPlayed: End -->

                <!-- noScoreReceived: If the match has been played and 
scores updated then display scores else show 'v' between team names-->
                <ion-row *ngIf="match?.homeScore != ''; else 
noScoreReceived" border="solid">
                    <ion-col col-2>{{match?.home}}</ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-1 style="text-align: right"> 
   {{match?.homeScore}}</ion-col> 
                    <ion-col col-1> - </ion-col> 
                    <ion-col col-1 style="text-align: left"> 
   {{match?.awayScore}}</ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-2> {{match?.away}}</ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                <ng-template #noScoreReceived>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col col-2>{{match?.home}}</ion-col> 
                        <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-1> v </ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
                        <ion-col col-2> {{match?.away}}</ion-col>
                     </ion-row>
                     </ng-template> 
                   <!-- noScoreReceived -->

                <ion-row> {{match?.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'h:mm a' }} 
   </ion-row>
                </ion-grid>    
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: Have you tried element.getBoundingClientRect()?

Comment: That also brings back 0. I'm beginning to think the problem is due to the fact that I'm creating ion-cards on the fly.

Comment: Adding my html file to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - my code was correct! The problem was on the html - I put the id on the ion-card-content tag rather than the ion-card tag ...d'oh!!